# How can I get eclipse to find my SDL libraries, and why can't it find them in the first place?

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, sdl

I am having an issue with getting my SDL libraries loaded into Eclipse properly. I included the libraries SDL2main and SDL2, and linked to them under properties>C/C++ General/>Paths and Symbols>libraries.

I get this error when I try to run my code.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\SDL2-2.26.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libSDL2main.a
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\SDL2-2.26.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libSDL2.a
```

Any clue why I am getting this error or how to fix it?

I initially had my folder with my libraries somewhere random, but I moved it to be in my C drive directly in case that might be the issue, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library names and library path must be separated. In the compiler command, the path should appear in the `-L` option. Under the `-l` (lowercase ell) option, only the library name should appear (without `lib` prefix and extension `.a`).

In Eclipse, only the library names (without path, without `lib` prefix and without `.a` extension) should be provided under C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries. The path should be provided under C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Library Paths.

Hence in your case, the library path `C:\SDL2-2.26.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib` must be provided under "Library Paths" and the library names `SDL2main` and `SDL2` must be provided under "Libraries".